# belongsTo doesn't do anything

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'sqlite',

  // SQLite only
  storage: 'db.sqlite'
});

var Driver = sequelize.define('driver', {
    auth:       Sequelize.STRING,
    name:       Sequelize.STRING,
    phone:      Sequelize.INTEGER,
    bank:       Sequelize.INTEGER,
    idNo:       Sequelize.STRING
});

var Hail = sequelize.define('hail', {
    lat:        Sequelize.INTEGER,
    lon:        Sequelize.INTEGER,
})

Hail.belongsTo(Driver);

sequelize.sync().then(function() {
    return Hail.create({
        lat: 123,
        lon: 1234
    });
}).then(function(driver) {
  console.log(driver.get({
    plain: true
  }));
});
```

I'm trying to use the belongs to method to connect a hail to a driver. It doesn't seem to do anything. The log doesn't output any belongsTo field and hail doesn't have a driverID column in the database. I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you've synced the database before adding the `belongsTo` call. The "sync" operation by default would not recreate the tables or modify the existing tables. You need to sync in a *"force" manner* once:

```
sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Note that this would destroy all the existing records you have in the tables.

Or, look into setting up the [migrations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/).